# Eigen Values of $\small\ \begin{bmatrix}e&0\\-e&1\end{bmatrix} $

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\ \begin{bmatrix}e&0\\-e&1\end{bmatrix} $

The answer is $\ λ = 1$ and $\ λ = e $

When you solve it quadratically you get a ugly expression.

Is there anyway to find the λ values easily?

edit: feel so stupid

Comment: haha, it always happens to all of us :)

Comment: Ain't that the truth!

Comment: You haven't even seen what a really ugly expression can be

Answer (score 5):

Ugly expression?
$$
 \begin{vmatrix}e-\lambda&0\\-e&1-\lambda\end{vmatrix} =(\lambda-e)(\lambda-1)
$$

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be an ugly expression, it should be an expression that gives you the answer right away, since the matrix is triangular.

$$\left|\begin{matrix}\lambda-e&0\\e&\lambda-1\end{matrix}\right| = 
(\lambda-e)(\lambda-1) - 0\cdot e = (\lambda-e)(\lambda-1)$$

which is a polynomial whose roots are $e$ and $1$.